# Data appear in fire base console but didn't appear in the simulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I create fire base Real time data base project and try to display student List in Recycler View, the data appear normally  in fire base console but didn't appear in the simulator ?

Here is the Recycler View Class code :

```
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.StudentHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Student> studentList;

public StudentAdapter(Context context, List<Student> studentList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.studentList = studentList;
}

@Override
public StudentHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student_row, parent, false);
    return new StudentHolder(row);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StudentHolder holder, int position) {
    final Student student = studentList.get(position);
    holder.studentNameTv.setText(student.getName());
    holder.studentAvgTv.setText(String.valueOf(student.getAverage()));

    holder.editStudentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditStudentActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", student.getName());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    holder.deleteStudentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
            Query query = ref.child("students").orderByChild("name").equalTo(student.getName());

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        snapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return studentList.size();
}

class StudentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView studentNameTv, studentAvgTv;
    Button deleteStudentBtn, editStudentBtn;

    public StudentHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        studentNameTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_name);
        studentAvgTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_avg);
        deleteStudentBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_student);
        editStudentBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_student);


    }
}
}
```

and Here is the Main Activity Class code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
StudentAdapter adapter;
DatabaseReference ref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference();

    ref.child("students").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         studentList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Student student = snapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                studentList.add(student);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            Collections.reverse(studentList);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    adapter = new StudentAdapter(MainActivity.this, studentList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Query fireQuery = ref.child("students").orderByChild("name").equalTo(query);
            fireQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        List<Student> searchList = new ArrayList<Student>();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Student student = snapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                            searchList.add(student);
                            adapter = new StudentAdapter(MainActivity.this, searchList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            adapter = new StudentAdapter(MainActivity.this, studentList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check firebase-ui https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android the adapter is incredibly

Comment: I think it's not Firebase problem. You should try to log the data out to see where is the problem.